# Containerzied React app and NGINX not serving on the localhost port I want

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, webpack

I have a containerized React app that I'm trying to test out building with webpack and serving the static generated files with the NGINX image, but it's not being displayed on the port I want locally. My WebPack file is outputting files in to a directory called dist so as you can see in my Dockerfile I'm going in to that directory and copying my files to the usr/share/nginx/html directory. Is there something else I'm missing in this file?
[image: Screen capture from dockerfile]

Comment: How are you building and running the container?

Comment: Build: `docker build -t app-image .`
Run: `docker run -d -p 3000:3000 app-image`

Comment: When I go to to `localhost:3000` on my computer it's saying that the page isn't working

Comment: Doesn't nginx serve on port 80? I think you might want to do `docker run -d -p 3000:80 app-image`. I'm not sure `EXPOSE` does anything in this case

Comment: OK great, I'll leave an answer

Answer (score 0):

Nginx serves on port 80, so when you run your container you'll want to do is map that port to port 3000 in your `docker run` command:

```
docker run -d -p 3000:80 app-image
```